# Vue router navigation guard prevent url from being changed

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router

I'm using a vuejs navigation guard to do some checks to check if a user is valid to enter a page. If the user doesn't meet the criteria I want the auth guard to return false which it currently does. However, when this is done the browser url gets set back to the previous url I came from. I don't want this behaviour instead I want the browser url to stay the same but still keep the user unable to use the page.

The reason I want this is because when the user hits refresh I want it to stay on the same page. I know this is intended vuejs behaviour for the router but I'm hoping to find a way around it. Here is the code for auth guard.

```
function guardRoute (to, from, next) {

    if (window.$cookies.get('kiosk_mode') === new DeviceUUID().get()) {
        return next(false)
    }

    return next()

}
```

Comment: You want the browser url to stay the same as what? The same as it was before the user attempted navigation?

Comment: Yep so if the user was going to /test but failed the check the url in the browser would still be /test

Comment: So if user was on /home and attempted /test but the route guard rejected the request you want the url to read /test even though they are still on the /home route?

Comment: Yep that's the behaviour I want.

Answer (score 1):

To reject a navigation but to not reset the url to its previous state you can reject the navigation with (requires vue 2.4.0+):

```
next(new Error('Authentication failure'));
```

And if you don't have router error handling then you need to include:

```
router.onError(error => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

See documentation for more details: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
history.pushState({}, null, '/test') before the return next(false);